# I get an empty list, have error when querying java spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**I have problems, when I do a query, the list is empty**

```
@Override 
    public List<QcReport> listQc3(double year, String hole_id) { 
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
        List report = session.createQuery("SELECT hole_id,year FROM QcReport where year = " +year+" AND hole_id = :hole_id")
//              .setParameter("year", year)  
                .setParameter("hole_id", hole_id)  
                .list();  
        System.out.println(report);
        return report; 
    }
```

controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/qc_table")
    public ModelAndView listReport(@ModelAttribute("report") QcReport assay,Model model) throws IOException {
        ModelAndView mod = new ModelAndView("qc_table"); 
        QcReport hole = new QcReport();
        List<QcReport> list = qcServ.listQc3(hole.getYear(),hole.getHole_id());
        model.addAttribute("listReporte", list);
//      mod.addObject("listReporte", list);   
        return mod;  
    }
```

the output of my code is empty, 
when I execute my code

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        qcreport0_.hole_id as col_0_0_,
        qcreport0_.year as col_1_0_ 
    from
        vw_dhqc_report qcreport0_ 
    where
        qcreport0_.year=0.0 
        and qcreport0_.hole_id=?
[]
```

Comment: Are there any default values set inside the constructor when `QcReport hole = new QcReport();` ? Are you sure that with the given parameters there are records to be fetched from database?

Comment: what are you seeing when you query the database using a DB client?

Are you getting results? and also try to print and see the result list.

Comment: If I get results, I know that my query is wrong but I don't know what the soucion is